# Firewall rule for cert-manager in GKE

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, lets-encrypt, nat

I'm using private GKE cluster with CloudNAT ,and trying to use cert-manager.

architecture
[image]

currently, with setting firewall rule(FW rule in picture), I got error as below

> Waiting for http-01 challenge propagation: failed to perform self check GET request 'http://MY_DOMAIN.COM/.well-known/acme-challenge/dP97kIy7Nj-PChMKGBnDGgZzuNRETH-Ys0pY5z40ugk': Get http://MY_DOMAIN.COM/.well-known/acme-challenge/dP97kIy7Nj-PChMKGBnDGgZzuNRETH-Ys0pY5z40ugk: dial tcp 222.333.444.555:80: connect: connection timed out

I already figure out that firewall rule caused that error, because if I have firewall rule which allow 0.0.0.0/0, port 22,443,80.

But I cannot figure out what IP address must be added in this rule.

I appreciate it if someone would give me any help

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65698600/waiting-for-http-01-challenge-propagation-failed-to-perform-self-check-get-requ

Comment: thank you. but the solution,  added another node to cluster and set Cert-Manager, doesn't fit on my env

Answer (score 0):

To configure your GKE Cluster with Cloud NAT you should follow this documentation[1](https://cloud.google.com/nat/docs/gke-example).

Have you followed it?
However, if you want to access from public Internet the best choice is Public endpoint access enabled, authorized networks disabled[2](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/private-cluster-concept).

Let us know if you have questions after checking the documentation.

Comment: I figured out that, it's because of the way to validate certificate by cert-manager.

I used HTTP-01, which need to get response from letsencrypt validation server. But these IP are not published by [*](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/faq/#what-ip-addresses-does-let-s-encrypt-use-to-validate-my-web-server) .  So I cannot set specific IP address in firewall rule. Solution is using DNS-01, which require cloudDNS access but not need to get response from public server.